# Edit Google Keep notes thru GhostText w/ advanced text editor?

Tags: google-chrome-extensions, text-editors, text-formatting, visual-studio-code

I tried to edit my Google Keep notes with Visual Code via GhostText... it is doable if you set the .tmp extension given by GhostText to use html syntax. And do a few additional steps:

1. Format the document so to have new lines
2. Remove the `<br>` as the new lines are in sync w\out them
3. Because of the formatting new lines are generated, so to remove double line breaks, I can do a find/replace with fast regexp: `\n\n` to `\n`

I wanted to take this route but find it to lucrative to do these every single time I want to open a note. So any suggestions to solve this would be welcome, things that I think would be good solutions:

1. Setting a hotkey in an advanced editor (preferred VS, Atom or NP++)
2. Launching the before mentioned ops when a .tmp is opened
3. Suggestions on a plugin/extension for an advanced editor
4. Suggestions on GhostText settings or replacement plugin/extension (FF or Chrome, both is ok)

Answer (score 0):

Consider **CudaText** editor with Python plugin for this task.

Plugin must handle `on_save_pre` event, or it can be called via Plugins/MyTask menu item + hotkey for this item. Task is simple in python. http://wiki.freepascal.org/CudaText_API

Without making plugin: you can install "Macros" plugin and record macro which has the job. Start recording of new macro, then do find-replaces ops, then stop recording of macro, save this macro. Replay macro as needed.

Comment: If you are just saying scripting, python is the solution then there is also the NP++ editor, has API that can be called with Python. And I think Visual Code or Atom is pretty much programmable but more with JS. When I'll have lots of time, will try to write up a plugin, until then I prefer just putting together existing things. Ideally I could bind together the VS Code actions to a hotkey.

Comment: @obeliksz Your question in vague- I dont understand what actions do you need. E.g. replace .... to ...., insert .... at line ends, etc.

Comment: I would like to edit my google keep notes from an advanced text editor instead of the browser, basically for this I would need a solution as described in the question my current solution involves too many steps to get started.

Comment: @obeliksz I improved my answer -about macros.